# Wrap detach append in that order not appending

Tags: jquery, append, detach

In order to do some DOM manipulation efficiently I am detaching an element. In the process, I came across this interesting situation:

```js
var $holder = $("#d");
var $wrapper = $("<div>").css("border","1px solid red");
$holder.wrap($wrapper);
$holder.detach();
$wrapper.append($holder);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d">a</div>
```

Whereby a div with the letter "a" in it is wrapped by a div with a red border. Then the div with the letter "a" is detached. Then the wrapping div is appending the detached "a". However, the letter "a" never re-appears.

What did I miss? What did I do wrong? How can I get the "a" back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wrap()` creates a HTML structure on the fly and inserts it into the DOM, that's why something like :

```
$(element).wrap('<div><span></span></div>')
```

works, so the variable $wrapper is not the same as the element that was actually created and inserted by `wrap()`, so you have get the element from the DOM again :

```
var $holder = $("#d");
var $wrapper = $('<div />', {style:'border:1px solid red;', id:'wrapper'});
$holder.wrap($wrapper);
$holder.detach();
$('#wrapper').append($holder);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hZLAg/3/)

from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

> The .wrap() function can take any string or object that could be
>   passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure. This
>   structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only
>   one inmost element. **A copy of this structure will be wrapped around
>   each of the elements** in the set of matched elements. This method
>   returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on `wrap` creating its own structure.

Answer (score -1):

Just do `$holder.detach($wrapper);`

edit: here's the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZLAg/1/)

Comment: That has no affect, nothing is detached. Here is an example of it not working: http://jsfiddle.net/7HvBz/